# Error while filtering data from a WMS with SLD LayerFeatureConstraints

Tags: wms, sld

Trying to filter a WMS layer with the following query:

https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&LAYERS=ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude&STYLES=&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=600&CRS=EPSG:2056&BBOX=2485410.215,1075268.1362500004,2833857.723749999,1295933.6975000016&SLD=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxcollombin/aea50283656b7d8344046e0c39ed149d/raw/f8a525d7bb28180e66962157a3e2d719a60c221e/ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude_features_constraints.sld

I'm getting the following error:

```
msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named &#39;ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude&#39;.
msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query. Check server logs
```

If it helps, here's a GetFeatureInfo request on the same layer to obtain the attributes and associated values:

https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&LAYERS=ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude&QUERY_LAYERS=ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude&CRS=EPSG:2056&BBOX=2531423.89,1155079.22,2532223.89,1155679.22&FEATURE_COUNT=2&HEIGHT=2&WIDTH=2&FORMAT=image/png&INFO_FORMAT=text/plain&I=1&J=1

Comment: what does the log file say happened?

Comment: what if you use `<ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>`

Comment: It doesn't work either.. I also asked about the swisstopo user group. I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Works in the end. The parameters and value passed were wrong.

```
https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?
SERVICE=WMS
&VERSION=1.3.0
&REQUEST=GetMap
&FORMAT=image/png
&TRANSPARENT=TRUE
&LAYERS=ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude
&STYLES=&
WIDTH=800&
HEIGHT=600
&CRS=EPSG:2056
&BBOX=2485410.215,1075268.1362500004,2833857.723749999,1295933.6975000016
&SLD=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxcollombin/aea50283656b7d8344046e0c39ed149d/raw/33bc789cf449dfcdc232837bea6840691a774482/ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude_features_constraints.sld&
```

Comment: Note you don't need to pass the styles parameter so the following works.  https://wms.geo.admin.ch/?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE&LAYERS=ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude&WIDTH=800&HEIGHT=600&CRS=EPSG:2056&BBOX=2485410.215,1075268.1362500004,2833857.723749999,1295933.6975000016&SLD=https://gist.githubusercontent.com/maxcollombin/aea50283656b7d8344046e0c39ed149d/raw/33bc789cf449dfcdc232837bea6840691a774482/ch.bafu.klima-co2_ausstoss_gebaeude_features_constraints.sld&